# H2 - duplicate key not throwing exception in Spring boot test when Persistable<ID> isNewObject set to true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am using H2 as test DB in a Java Spring Boot application, but when I want to catch a "duplicate key" exception when trying to insert an duplicate ID/PK, H2 does not throw anything.

With Postman all is fine and nice, I just cannot pass the test.

The real DB is PostgreSQL, and it does throw exception when I integration test with Postman. But when unit testing I think it is not necessary to load real DB so I chose H2.

H2 config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:tesdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;mode=MySQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.datasource.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true # if you need console
```

Bean definition:

```
@Entity
@Data
@JsonComponent
@Table(name="bin_info")
public class BinInfo implements Serializable, Persistable<String>{ //with Persistable we can check ID duplicate
    @Id
    @Size(min=6, max=8)
    @Column(name="bin")
    @JsonProperty("bin")
    private String bin;

    ...

    /**
     * Property for identifying whether the object is new or old,
     * will insert(new) or update(old)
     * If is new and id/bin is duplicate, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException will be thrown.
     * If is old and id/bin is duplicate, just updates. Hibernate save() will upsert and no complain.
     */
    @Transient
    private boolean isNewObject;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.bin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNewObject;
    }
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.bin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNewObject;
    }
```

The controller `insert` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> insertBIN(@Valid @RequestBody BinInfo bin_info, HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<String, Object> errors = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
        bin_info.setCreatedAt(now);
        bin_info.setUpdatedAt(now);
        bin_info.setNewObject(true); //if set to true, bin duplicate -> exception and return 200; then we avoid "select to check duplicate first"
        BinInfo saved = repository.save(bin_info);
        // if is new, created(201); if not, updated(status OK, 200)
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(saved);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e0) {
        log.warn("Update BIN due to duplicate", e0); // exception details in log
        //if duplicate, change newObject to false and save again. And return.
        bin_info.setNewObject(false);
        BinInfo saved = repository.save(bin_info);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()          // <<<<<< here I define "save duplicate=update=200, OK"
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(saved);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Cannot save BinInfo. ", e); // exception details in log
        errors.put("error", "Cannot save BIN"); // don't expose to user
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(Utilities.jsonBuilder(errors));
    }
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void testBinInfoControllerInsertBIN() throws Exception {
    when(this.repository.save(any(BinInfo.class))).thenReturn(mockBinInfo);
    String content_double_quotes = "{\"bin\":\"123456\", "
                    + "\"json_full\":\"" + this.json_full + "\", "
                    + "\"brand\":\"" + this.brand + "\", "
                    + "\"type\":\"" + this.type + "\", "
                    + "\"country\":\"" + this.country + "\", "
                    + "\"issuer\":\"" + this.issuer + "\", "
                    + "\"newObject\":true, "
                    + "\"new\":true, "
                    + "\"createdAt\":\"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200\", "
                    + "\"updatedAt\":\"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200\"}";
    log.info("JSON input: " + content_double_quotes);

    //save the entity for the first time(newObject==true, new=true) and should return 201
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/insert")
            .content(content_double_quotes) //json cannot have single quote; must be double
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            )
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.bin", is(this.bin)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.json_full", is(this.json_full)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.brand", is(this.brand)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.type", is(this.type)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.country", is(this.country)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.issuer", is(this.issuer)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdAt", is("18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.updatedAt", is("18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200")));

    //save the same entity, new == true, and should return 200
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/insert")
            .content(content_double_quotes) //json cannot have single quote; must be double
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());   //<<<<< here I always get 201, not 200. With Postman I get 200 instead.
}
```

Note that `mockBinInfo` has `isNewObject` always set to `true`, meaning that it should throw exception when finding duplicate PK in the second insertion, but it is not happening. This is required by `Persistable<ID>` interface, which will tell DB whether or not to persist when ID is duplicate or not.

- if `isNew()` returns `true`, will throw exception when ID is duplicate
- otherwise, will update silently

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories) for more information(searching "Persistable").

EDIT:

I also noticed that H2 seems not to support Spring `Persistable<ID>` and always return `new=false` in the saved entity.

Log details:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /insert
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {"bin":"123456", "json_full":"{'brand':'visa', 'type':'credit', 'country':'USA', 'issuer':'BigBank'}", "brand":"visa", "type":"credit", "country":"USA", "issuer":"BigBank", "newObject":"true", "new":"true", "createdAt":"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200", "updatedAt":"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.xxxxx.binlookup.controller.BinInfoController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.xxxxx.binlookup.controller.BinInfoController.insertBIN(com.xxxxx.binlookup.model.BinInfo,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"id":"123456","newObject":false,"new":false,"bin":"123456","json_full":"{'brand':'visa', 'type':'credit', 'country':'USA', 'issuer':'BigBank'}","brand":"visa","type":"credit","country":"USA","issuer":"BigBank","createdAt":"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200","updatedAt":"18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `save()` on an existing entity, Hibernate will not persist it again, but will just update the entity.

Comment: Yes but maybe I was not clear: `Persistable` enables you to mark the object as new or old,  thus adopting different strategies when saving. See edits of my question.

Answer (score 0):

At last I abort this test, and bypasses it by not examining the exception. It is still a bug.